# Azure Connection for Data Reader

Tags: c#, string, azure, connection

I've created an App and have created the Azure database which I can connect to and populate with no issues.

I have a SQL query that I have hard coded in to a controller and view using a Data Reader, as there's a Pivot and it was the only way I could get it to work correctly.

```
con.Open();
com.Connection = con;
com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TABLE]"

dr = com.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
// Assign the variables
}
```

[DatabaseName].[dbo].[TABLE]  This is the part where I'm having issues, throwing an invalid Object name for the Table, it works locally but not when trying to connect to Azure.

Can someone help me with a fix please?

Many thanks

Comment: there must be something wrong with the connection string.  check if the `con` object looks OK while debugging.

Comment: You need to use the Azure Sql Database to provide data. Refer [Azure Web App with Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) for more information

Comment: Hi, I can use all of the CRUD stuff line on Azure, it's just this one controller page, that uses the PIVOT that's causing the issue.    I think it's the way I'm referencing the tables.    [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TABLE]

Answer (score 0):

Cross-database and cross-instance queries using three or four part names are not supported in Azure Sql Database.  The differences in TSQL are documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server?view=azuresql